# Create Simple CDN

Tags: php

I want to create simple CDN for my site

so let me explain what I want to do

I have a list of available server list ( my servers )

In Main servers that user upload image , I have file paths

I will get server list and copy to one (or all) of them randomly .

But the problem is here :

how can I copy file from main server to child servers ?

Comment: What about having the other servers digging thru the main server and getting images from there when missing?

Comment: Why don't you use something like Amazon S3 + CloudFront?

Comment: They are high cost for storage , I need many storage ...

Comment: Why would you use php for this problem? `rsync` would be a better fit.

Comment: What part of CDN benefits are you looking for? You could use network storage or share the folder. Rsync like @Bart suggested.

Comment: should be more specific about how you want this `CDN` to work. Why copy files all over and not store them on one server?

Answer (score 0):

Replicate your files and folders using DRBD. So that any file operations in any servers will be replicated to all other servers.

Use asynchronous replication , It is suitable for replications over a long distance.